# How do I make my Last Image Recovery Policy topic survive broker restarts?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have configured a topic in ActiveMQ with lastImageSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy. It works as expected in that the broker persists the last message sent to the topic and when a new consumer subscribes to that topic it receives that last message:

1. producer publishes N messages
2. consumer A subscribes to the topic; 1 message is received
3. consumer B subscribes to the topic; same 1 message is received

However, the message is lost when I restart the broker. This is the sequence of events:

1. producer publishes N messages
2. broker is restarted
3. consumer subscribes to the topic; nothing is received

Is it possible to enable persistence of that last message (Last Image) so that it is persisted even across broker restarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.  If you need message durability then you either need to use a Queue, or use a Durable Topic subscription in order to keep messages around after restart.  The broker has some convenience features for Topics such as recovery policies but they are no real substitute for the stronger guarantees that exists for Queue based messaging, so if you need that then you must use those mechanisms.